# How to provide DataSource properties in spring boot application after deployment of the application

Tags: java, spring, database, spring-boot

I am developing a server that is configured to a PostgreSQL database, I want that application takes data source properties ( username, password, port, hostname etc.) from the client specific to his database so how can I take input from the client and pass that configuration after deployment because I want to distribute only WAR file of the server

Answer (score 0):

Yes You can Add configuration Dynamically from the Client side. We can achieve this concept by spring-boot hibernate.

--> You have to create an class to Auto congifure the propertise.
I am sharing my sample code to configure the propertise.

```
    package com.spring.hibernate.config;

import java.util.Properties;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class Configurations {
    
    @Value("${db.url}")
    private String URL;
    
    @Value("${db.username}")
    private String USERNAME;
    
    @Value("${db.password}")
    private String PASSWORD;
    
    @Value("${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}")
    private String HBM2DDL;
    
    @Value("${hibernate.show_sql}")
    private String SHOW_SQL;
    
    @Value("${hibernate.dialect}")
    private String DIALECT;
    
    @Value("${spring.entitymanager.packagestoscan}")
    private String packagesToscan;
    
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setUrl(URL);
        dataSource.setUsername(USERNAME);
        dataSource.setPassword(PASSWORD);
        return dataSource;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(packagesToscan);
        Properties hibernatePropertise = new Properties();
        hibernatePropertise.put("hibernate.dialect", DIALECT);
        hibernatePropertise.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", HBM2DDL);
        hibernatePropertise.put("hibernate.show_sql", SHOW_SQL);
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernatePropertise);
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

Have a configuration class in the above structure to configure the application Properties file.
And have your application properties file as follow.

```
db.url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/data_db
db.username: root
db.password: 8452

    hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
    hibernate.show_sql=true
    hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
    spring.entitymanager.packagestoscan: com.spring.hibernate
```

Use the above sample code. Still any logics needed have a command for me...Thank You..